# Django serializers, foreignkeys error

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

On the serializer im trying to show the person data into Employee but im getting this error  AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `persons` on serializer `EmployeeSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Employee` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Employee' object has no attribute 'persons'.

Here's my models.py

```
class Person(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    curp = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    rfc = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=20)



class Employee(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    joining_date = models.DateField()
    salary = models.DecimalField(18, decimal_places=2, max_digits=50)
    status = models.IntegerField()
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='persons', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    branch = models.ForeignKey(Branch)
```

Serializers

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('name', 'curp', 'rfc', 'gender')

class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    persons = PersonSerializer(many=True)


    class Meta:
       model = Employee
       fields = ('persons')
```

It's my first time working on django so i dont get how to call the foreing keys.
In my database i have the table Employee with 3 foreign keys (user, person and branch) 
Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your Employee serializer you should changed name persons variable to person, and   i assume since only one person would be related with employee  object you can change the many to False

```
class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    person = PersonSerializer(many=False, )


    class Meta:
       model = Employee
       fields = ('person')
```

Comment: So if i want to return all the data from Person i would have to add all the field in the return, and in the serializers add one by one ?

Comment: sorry, first i misunderstood your question i edited it to way you want. You actually using it right but you need to use actual field name not the related name when you serialize the fields of foreign key